# Can't render a Text view and DatePicker together in a sidebar list section in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios15

Consider the following SwiftUI View:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var selectedDate = Date()
  var body: some View {
      List {
        Section(header: Text("TextView and DatePicker")) {
          VStack {
            Text("TextView")
            DatePicker(selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: .date) {
              Text("DatePicker")
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .listStyle(.sidebar)
  }
}
```

With the sidebar list style, I should be able to collapse and expand list sections. However compare the results in iOS 14 (works) vs iOS 15 (doesn't work):

[image: Expanding and collapsing works okay in iOS 14]
[image: The section initially renders okay in iOS 15, but after collapsing and expanding it, nothing gets rendered in the section.]

As you can see, in iOS 15 if I collapse the section, it no longer renders when I expand it again.

The problem seems very specific to having both `Text` and `DatePicker` views inside the section. Any other combinations seem to work okay.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there a bug in iOS 15? Are there any workarounds if I need to render this?

Comment: Most likely a bug. A possible work around is to "attach" 
something like `.frame(height: 111)` to the `VStack` or `Section`.
When I do this get a constraints warning in the console.

Comment: @workingdog Good idea, and this fixes the issue in the trivial example in the question, however in my app the content in the `Section` is dynamic and I don't know what the height will be.

Comment: Have logged a bug with Apple. For the moment we're working around this by removing all DatePickers and replacing them with TextFields.